# Warning: Couldn't read data from file "image.jpg", this makes an empty POST

Tags: java, sh

I created a shell script having a curl command to send any image to a server.
Running the shell script manually through git bash works perfectly.

I need to execute this shell script on Linux box using java code. But when i run it i see following error in the output:

> Getting error: Warning: Couldn't read data from file "image.jpg", this makes an empty POST.

Java code:

```
String filePath=directoryPath + "/APIData/email_template.sh";
File sendImage = new File(filePath);
if(!sendImage.isFile()){
throw new IllegalArgumentException("The file " + filePath + " does not exist");
}
String[] command = {"/bin/bash","-c", directoryPath + "/APIData/email_template.sh", "argument1","argument2"};
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process proc = p.start();
String line;
outputFile = new File(directoryPath + "/target/response.txt");
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
String s;
while ((s = read.readLine()) != null) {
bw.write(s);
}
read.close();
bw.close();
```

Here is the email_template.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "First arg: $1"
echo "Second arg: $2"

FIRST=$1
SECOND=$2

curl -v -X POST "https://ipaddress-host/$FIRST/template?mimeType=image/png" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -k --data-binary "@image.png" -H "Authorization: $SECOND"
```

image.png is present in same folder where the .sh file is. Why i am getting

"Warning: Couldn't read data from file "image.jpg", this makes an empty POST."

Answer (score 1):

Before

```
Process proc = p.start();
```

insert

```
p.directory( new File( directoryPath, "APIData" ));
```

Here is the documentation of [java.lang.ProcessBuilder.directory(java.io.File)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory-java.io.File-)